# "Some is controversial, and some is my opinions" — is this grammatical?

Tags: expressions, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I came across the expression

> ... some is controversial, and some is my opinions.

Is this correct? I wonder if “... some are my opinions” might be more correct.

Comment: Where did you "come across" this expression? Your alternative might be "more correct" in the general sense, but I could see a writer deliberately using the original for several reasons: to sound colloquial, to be deliberately jarring, to be comical, to force parallelism, etc. (I will gladly reverse my downvote if you provide some contextual background as an edit to your question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both clauses can be used correctly and are grammatical in the proper context:

> The content of this book is mixed: some is controversial, and some is my opinions.

In both cases, "some" functions as a [pronoun](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/some) that refers to a part of the content: "Some *of the content* is controversial, and some *of the content* is my opinions".  Neither sentence is elegant, but that's a style problem and not a grammatical problem.

English isn't always pretty. <:-(

Comment: "...some is my opinion" would make it slightly more elegant though. +1; I shan't complete the answer I was writing as this says the same thing.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Yes, you're quite right that the singular would make it more elegant. I didn't think of that. Excellent point.

Comment: "English isn't always pretty" should be the site's subtitle.